# Find a possible neutral such that $1g = g$ and $g1 \neq g$, or $g1 = g$ and $1g \neq g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm thinking about some simple counterexamples on Group Theory.

"Choice a set $G$ and find a possible $1 \in G$ such that $1g \neq g1$ for some $g \in G$"

Basically I want to find a possible neutral such that $1g = g$ and $g1 \neq g$, or $g1 = g$ and $1g \neq g$ for some $g$.

Is it possible?

---

**Edit.** I think I did not write correctly. I'll try to be clearer.

In the definition of a group we have the axiom:

> "There is a $1 \in G$ such that $1g = g = g1$ for all $g \in G$."

Why is necessary to verify $1g = g$ and $g1 = g$? I think that the reason is: in a non-group, we can find a element such that $1g = g$ but $g1 \neq g$ or $g1 = g$ and $1g \neq g$.

Comment: If you did find one then that would violate the Axiom of Identity.

Comment: If you have $1g=g\neq g1$, then what you have is not a group. It's very possible in other algebraic structures, though. For instance, the integers where $ab$ is defined as $b-a$, we have $0b=b\neq b0$.

Comment: @Arthur exactly! Is an example of this that I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

No. In any group $G$ with identity $1$, $g1 = 1g = g$ for any $g \in G$.

Suppose $1g = g$. Then $gg = g(1g) = (g1)g$. Right-multiplying both sides by $g^{-1}$ leaves $g = g1$.

Comment: Yes, I dont know if I wrote correctly, but I mean a possible neutral $1$ (sure, that $1$ is not really a neutral). Its just for justify the definition $g1 = g = 1g$ and not just $1g = g$ or $g1 = g$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking for. There is only one identity (I think this is what you mean by neutral, so correct me if this is wrong) element in any group.

Comment: I've edited. I tried to be clearer.

Comment: Okay. As noted in my answer, if such a set is closed under the associative operation of multiplication and inverses, we always have $1g = g \implies g = 1g$. So really, if the other group axioms hold, then we only need that there exists a $1 \in G$ such that $1g = g$ for all $g \in G$.